# compiling ffmpeg for iPhone SDK 4.3 [error: is unable to create an executable file.]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, ffmpeg

Like many others.. I'm compiling ffmpeg using gas preprocessor

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-October/077701.html

This is my command

```
./configure --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1' --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk --enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm7 --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic
```

the error:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
```

I looked up the `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` folder using `Finder`..
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 was there..

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 0):

Guess; Try switching the compiler to llvm (but not gas).